# Scraping SEDE query results with caching

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, stackexchange, beautifulsoup

I use this script to scrape the results of a SEDE page and return as a [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) object.

A small twist is that if I don't use a SEDE query manually in the browser for a few days, then non-interactive downloads get empty results. (I suspect there is a robot test there.)

Rather than fixing the robot test issue, my workaround is to cache successfully downloaded pages, and use the cache when downloading is not working well.

```
import logging
import os

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
CACHE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.cache')


def fetch_sede_soup(label, url):
    def is_valid(soup):
        for script in soup.findAll('script'):
            if 'resultSets' in script.text:
                return True
        return False

    if not os.path.isdir(CACHE_DIR):
        os.mkdir(CACHE_DIR)

    logging.info('fetching {} as {}'.format(label, url))
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    cache_path = os.path.join(CACHE_DIR, '{}.html'.format(label))
    debug_cache_path = os.path.join(CACHE_DIR, '{}-debug.html'.format(label))

    if is_valid(soup):
        logging.info('updating cache')
        with open(cache_path, 'w') as fh:
            fh.write(html)
        return soup

    with open(debug_cache_path, 'w') as fh:
        fh.write(html)

    logging.warning('result not valid')
    if os.path.exists(cache_path):
        logging.info('using previous cache')
        with open(cache_path) as fh:
            return BeautifulSoup(fh)
```

Can this be written better?

In case it helps, here are some sample output files:

- [sede-output.html](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/janosgyerik/robosanta/4de3f8e00cd0b2d2ac82ab26b64c7d4f59680a4b/python/robosanta/robosanta/tests/extractors/sede-output.html) - a successful download.
- [sede-output-debug.html](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/janosgyerik/robosanta/c3e9770f81c599153ad037693461a63b4241d4aa/python/robosanta/robosanta/tests/stackexchange/sede-output-debug.html) - a "failed" download (empty results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shows that you've written code before, so style wise there is not much to comment upon. What I would like to comment upon is a few points on code structure:

- *Single responsibility concern* – Your function is name `fetch_sede_soup()` and all actions are related to this. However it still creates the `CACHE_DIR` if needed, write output files, verifies validity in inner function. This could be separated into more functions, although it is not extremely large and hard to get the overview of.

  One point I would at least add a new function is related to the `return soup` near the middle. Code after this seems to be error handling, but it is somewhat hidden by the `return` and as such it is not very clear. If you moved the remaining part into a function you would see a `return soup` followed by a `else:` clause calling the error handling.
- *Add comments and docstrings* – As a side effect of the different aspects your function handles, I would at least add more comments within the code. This could justify keeping more within the larger function, whilst still maintaining readability
- *Add error handling around `mkdir`* – Especially around external os calls, like `mkdir`, I would add `try ... except` code to handle potential error situations. This code related to creating the `CACHE_DIR` could possibly be done before this method is called as part of initialization.

But in general, nice, clean code, but a little thin on documentation and error handling of os-operations.